# How to split a text file into multiple parts in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, text-files, realloc

What i need to do, is to take a file of n lines, and for every x lines, create a new file with the lines of the original file. An example would be this:

Original File:

> stefano
>
> angela
>
> giuseppe
>
> lucrezia

In this case, if x == 2,  3 file would be created, in order:

First file:

> stefano
>
> angela

Second FIle:

> giuseppe
>
> lucrezia

Third File:

> lorenzo

What i've done so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  N 10

int getlines(FILE *fp)
{
  int c = 0;
  int ch;
  do{
  ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      c++;
    }
  }while(ch != EOF);
  fseek(fp, 0 , SEEK_SET);
  return c;
}

int ix = 0;

void Split(FILE *fp, FILE **fpo, int step, int lines, int *mem)
{
FILE **fpo2 = NULL;
char * filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
char * ext = ".txt";
char  number[2];
for(int i = ix; i < *mem; i++)
{
  itoa(i+1, number,10);
  strcpy(filename, "temp");
  strcat(filename, number);
  strcat(filename, ext);

if(!(fpo[i] = fopen(filename, "w")))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error in writing\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

}
  char ch;
  int  c = 0;
  do{
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c", ch);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      c++;
    }
    if(c >= step)
    {
      c = 0;
      ix++;
      if(ix >= *mem && (ix*step) <= lines)
      {
      *mem = *mem + 1;
      fpo2 = realloc(fpo, sizeof(FILE*)*(*mem));
      Split(fp, fpo2, step, lines, mem);
      }
    }
    putc(ch, fpo[ix]);
  }while(ch != EOF);

}



int main()
{
FILE * fp;
if(!(fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int mem = N;
int lines = getlines(fp);
int step = lines/N;

FILE **fpo = malloc(sizeof(FILE *)*N);

Split(fp, fpo, step, lines, &mem);


exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm stack with segmentation error, i couldn't find the bug doing

`gdb myprogram`

```
run

bt
```

I really appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I've changed some things and now it works, but it creates an additional file that contains strange characters. I need to still adjust some things:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  N 10

int getlines(FILE *fp)
{
  int c = 0;
  int ch;
  do{
  ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      c++;
    }
  }while(ch != EOF);
  fseek(fp, 0 , SEEK_SET);
  return c;
}

int ix = 0;

void Split(FILE *fp, FILE **fpo, int step, int lines, int *mem)
{
FILE **fpo2 = NULL;
char * ext = ".txt";
for(int i = ix; i < *mem; i++)
{
  char * filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
  char * number = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);

  itoa(i+1, number,10);
  strcpy(filename, "temp");
  strcat(filename, number);
  strcat(filename, ext);

if(!(fpo[i] = fopen(filename, "w")))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error in writing\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
free(number);
free(filename);
}
  char ch;
  int  c = 0;
  do{
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c", ch);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      c++;
    }
    if(c >= step)
    {
      c = 0;
      ix++;
      if(ix >= *mem && ((ix-1)*step) <= lines)
      {
      *mem = *mem + 1;
      fpo2 = realloc(fpo, sizeof(FILE*)*(*mem));
      Split(fp, fpo2, step, lines, mem);
      }
    }
    putc(ch, fpo[ix]);
  }while(ch != EOF);

}



int main()
{
FILE * fp;
if(!(fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int mem = N;
int lines = getlines(fp);
int step = lines/N;

FILE **fpo = malloc(sizeof(FILE *)*N);

Split(fp, fpo, step, lines, &mem);


exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `split -l 2 filename temp`

Comment: ty for the hint, i did a workaround and now it works

Comment: One additional file gets created, i need to still adjust some things in the code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code. But first I think you need to fix the most important thing

```
int step = lines/N;
```

Here `step` is 0 if your input file has less than N lines of text.  This is because `lines` and `N` both are integer and integer division is rounding down.

Comment: Yeah, that's becuase i already know that my file has a large amount of lines

Answer (score 0):

I won't fix your code, but I'll help you with it.  Some changes I
suggest:

- Instead of **getlines**, use **getline**(3) from the standard
  library.
- `fseek(fp, 0 , SEEK_SET)` is pointless.
- In `char * filename = malloc(sizeof(char)*64)`, note that
  both arguments to malloc are constant, and the size is arbitrary.
  These days, it's safe to allocate filename buffers statically,
  either on the stack or with *static*: `char filename[PATH_MAX]`.
  You'll want to use `limits.h` to get that constant.
- Similarly you have no need to dynamically allocate your FILE
  pointers.
- Instead of

  `itoa(i+1, number,10);
  strcpy(filename, "temp");
  strcat(filename, number);
  strcat(filename, ext);`

  use `sprintf(filename, "temp%d%s", i+1, ext)`
- get familiar with **err**(3) and friends, for your own convenience.

Finally, your recursive **Split** is -- how shall we say it? -- a nightmare.  Your whole program
should be something like:

```
open input
while getline input
  if nlines % N == 0
      create output filename with 1 + n/N
      open output
  write output
  nlines++
```